# How to show only 2 decimals in WooCommerce prices using php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, user-roles

How can I display only 2 decimal places on all sites on the web without breaking the function that adds text to prices?

The online store is linked to the inventory and manufacturing program, and due to the rounding of decimals in WooCommerce, errors occur when entering orders in the program.

We fixed this by adding 3 decimal places in the WooCommerce settings, in "Currency Options"

The problem is that the prices with 3 decimal places in the store are very ugly, they are nice and I wanted to change so that only 2 decimal places were displayed.

In part we have achieved it with the help of an acquaintance who created the following function which he filters to leave only two decimal places in the store, without affecting the WooCommerce configuration:

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment of the colleague @MosheGross, I realized that the question is not well formulated, since only changing the priority of the filter, in the store they show 2 decimal places and the text of the prices works.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cambiar_num_decimales', 5, 2 );
```

But I need 2 decimal places to be displayed on all web sites where prices are displayed: on the cart page, at checkout, etc.

How would this be possible?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cambiar_num_decimales', 5, 2 );

function cambiar_num_decimales( $price, $product ) {
    $decimales = 2; // Número de decimales que deseas mostrar
    $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) ), array( 'decimals' => $decimales ) );
    return $price;
}
```

The drawback is that this function makes only 2 decimal places visible in the store, but it eliminates the text that we have added to differentiate the prices, since we have 2 different texts (P.V.P AND wholesale text: P.V.M.) because the store sells at wholesale customers, who have different prices than other users.

To display the text based on the user role, I have the following code that worked perfectly:

```
function my_get_current_user_roles() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
      return $roles; // This will returns an array
  } else {
      return  array();
  }
}

function custom_price_message( $price ) { 
  global $post; 
  $product_id = $post->ID; 
  $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
  $textafter = "";
  if(!empty($roles)) { 
      if (in_array("wholesale_customer", $roles)) {
          $textafter = ''; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
      if (in_array("customer", $roles)  or in_array("administrator",$roles)) {
          $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
  }
  else{
      $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; // Or whatever you want
  }
    
  return $price . '' . $textafter . ''; //class textafter para el  

} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message');
```

I did tests but I only get the prices to be removed or the text to be removed, no matter how hard I try it doesn't work

How can I correct this without removing the functionality of the texts?

Some of the options that I have tried like this one only works with normal customers, it shows 2 decimal places and does not remove the P.V.P text, however for wholesale customers it does not work, since it changes the wholesale price to the retail price and does not add either the P.V.M text:

```
function my_get_current_user_roles() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $user = wp_get_current_user();
      $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
      return $roles; // This will returns an array
  } else {
      return  array();
  }
}

function custom_price_message( $price, $product ) { 
  $product_id = $product->get_id(); 
  $roles = my_get_current_user_roles();
  $textafter = "";
  if(!empty($roles)) { 
      if (in_array("wholesale_customer", $roles)) {
          $textafter = ''; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
      if (in_array("customer", $roles)  or in_array("administrator",$roles)) {
          $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; //texto que vamos agregar 
      }
  }
  else{
      $textafter = ' P.V.P.'; // Or whatever you want
  }
  $decimales = 2; // Número de decimales que deseas mostrar
  $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) ), array( 'decimals' => $decimales ) );
  $price_with_text = $price . ' ' . $textafter;
  return $price_with_text; 
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Easiest solution would be to change the priority of the first filter like this `add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cambiar_num_decimales', 5, 2 );`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This seems to work. But I keep having other problems, since in the cart page, and in the class="cart_totals " and in the "checkout-sidebar", the 3 decimal places are still shown. Maybe I should edit the question because I have not formulated it correctly, since 2 decimal places must be displayed throughout the web